# Использование переменных php в кавычках ECHO

Tags: php

Есть два куска php кода.
Первый с кавычками.

```
echo "<option value='".$key['id']."'>".$key['name']." (".$key['width']." x ".$key['height'].")"."</option>";
```

И второй без кавычек.

```
echo "<option value='$key[id]'>$key[name] ($key[width] x $key[height])</option>";
```

Оба работают. Вопрос такой:
Является ли второй вариант приемлемым с точки зрения правильности кода?
Можно ли использовать такие конструкции повсеместно?
Спасибо заранее за консультацию.

Comment: @Cactus на самом деле те тесты сделаны очень давно. Сейчас надо бы заново замерить и причем на разных версиях

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, возможно. Но спасибо их автора и за то, что есть!)

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии странно, а где одинарные кавычки? ведь вся соль была раньше между применением одинарных кавычек и конкатинации VS двойных кавычек.... а всё потому, что в них была разница, о которой вы видимо не знаете

Comment: @Cactus неактуальные данные - бессмысленны)

Comment: Кроме того нет варианта "{$test}". В общем да, тесты хорошие, но морально устаревшие, а что касается сабжа, то как по мне, второй вариант ужасен (аргументов не будет).

Comment: Я бы не назвал второй вариант ужасным. Визуально я могу за секунду прочиать его смысл. А вот первый - нужно напрячься.

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии в ответе написал, посмотрите. Если бы вы в вопросе немного больше разметки привели — на ней бы показал. Так как у вас явно цикл `for` используется — для него есть альтернативный синтаксис для таких случаев. Да и не это тестами мерить надо — это фетиш какой-то переменные мерить :)

Answer (score 5):

Вижу, что вы не присваиваете результат переменной, а выводите его, поэтому оба «неверно». PHP не для этого изначально был создан, чтобы разметку выводить.

Правильно и удобно для поддержки проекта в дальнейшем будет:

```
<option value="<?= $key['id'] ?>">
    <?= $key['name'] ?> (<?= $key['width'] ?> x <?= $key['height'] ?>)
</option>
```

**Старайтесь изначально разделять логику от представления.**

Так же когда начнете шаблонизаторы использовать — будет проще под них разметку изменить.

Изучите основы синтаксиса языка PHP, в частности:

- [Изолирование от HTML](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)
- [Альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: `<?= $key['name'] ?> (<?= $key['width'] ?> x <?= $key['height'] ?>)` - вот это нихрена не правильно и не удобно. Такой код сложно как писать (руки отваливаются от постоянных `<?=?>`) так и читать. Лучше все-таки написать что-то вроде `<?= "$key[name] ($key[width] x $key[height])" ?>`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov правильнее вообще писать `{{ $key['name'] }} ({{ $key['width'] }} x {{ $key['height'] }})`, но в любом случае объединять встроки не стоит. разметка дело такое - всегда понадобится втюхать пару тегов между. Так что пусть будет одна переменная - один вывод

Comment: @PavelMayorov ахахах, ну да, ну да. Я только сокращенным синтаксисом даже не пользуюсь (ответ подкорректировали), чтобы поддерживаеть единообразие. Бывает, что нужно что-то в несколько строчек вывести, например, <?php $num = 123; $str = "String"; ?>. Но против них ничего особо не имею.

Comment: С Павлом согласен, когда дело дойдет до сложной разметки — по другому на это взгляните. Разметка должна быть «чистой». А что если у тегов классы будут, несколько классов, а с id? А если именование будет по БЭМ методологии? Дело конечно ваше. Пуская ответ для других будет — новички прочтут, может для других будет полезно.

Comment: Еще вопрос в команде: если в команде принято писать так `<?=`, значит либо я пишу так, либо... ну вообщем понятно. И когда человек будет ваш код читать — очень важно, чтобы максимально с первого взгяда было понятно что и как...

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать обе варианта. Только для группы разработчиков надо выбрать одно из двух вариантов. Так как не будет красиво на одном сайте использовать обе варианта.

По мне первый вариант предпочтительный. Я по крайне мере так пишу.

Плюс первого варианта: Все редакторы правильно подкрашивает переменные.
Плюс второго варианта: Код короче получается. 
Минус второго варианта: Если вы захотите вставить символ - " то необходимо писать \"

Comment: Технически верным тоже считаю первый вариант. И пишу так же первым. А тут пошли ну уж больше длинные вставки в одно ECHO перемнных, объектов и решил задаться вопросом насколько это "легально" в среде разработки.

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии писать нужно так, чтобы потом было просто понимать и поддерживать код. В этом разрезе наиболее правильным является вариант из ответа AlexanderBragin. Если же сравнивать два ваших варианта, то я бы предпочел вариант 2, так как он банально человекочитаемей. А подсвечивать переменные внутри текста сейчас умеет любая среда разработки.